# Azure Functions : With a TableResult, how do I see a property?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am successfully retrieving a Table Row on Azure:

```
TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Retrieve<MyEntity>(partitionKey, rowkey);
TableResult result  = table.Execute(operation);

if (result.Result != null)
{
}
```

I need to look at the Result to see if MyEntity.MyProperty == true

I cannot get to view the actual MyEntity result e.g.

1. `log.Info(result.Result);`  returns     `Submission#0+MyEntity`
2. `log.Info(result.Result.MyProperty) : object does not contain a definition for MyProperty and no extension method MyProperty accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found`

With a TableResult, how do I see a property?

Comment: Have you considered using [input binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input) to read from Table Storage?

Comment: Hi Mikhail, a bit more info : this is a HTTP Trigger, and we receive a MyEntity in the req . I then want to find the existing MyEntity in Table Storage, and do a check on that existing MyEntity. Do yo think I should add an input binding to the whole MyEntity table, and then loop the input binding table to find the one with partition/row key == req?

Comment: See the first example in the link I gave you. You can use input binding to retrieve just one table entity by binding to properties of HTTP request, if partition and row keys are part of request payload.

Comment: See also [Bind to custom input properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#bind-to-custom-input-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast `result.Result` to your entity class:

```cs
((MyEntity)result.Result).MyProperty
```